# How can I render a `Widget` between two other `Widget`s, which must be next to each other?

Tags: flutter, layout

For the sake of this question, let's say I'm making a "game" in Flutter. In this game, I am wanting a draggable (like click-and-drag then retain its position on the screen kind of a thing, not the `Draggable`/`DragTarget` stuff) widget that slides between two other widgets, like so:

[image: what I want]

For the sake of conversation, I'm going to name the three widgets you see on the screen. There's "cable box-top", "cable box-bottom", and "audio jack". I want to be able to slide the audio jack widget between the cable box-bottom and cable box-top widgets so it looks like it's being slid into an audio jack plug.

My first thought was to render a `Column` for the cable box, then the audio jack, and maybe I could get it to slide between them somehow using some flutter-positioning magic I didn't know yet. Turns out that didn't work, and the audio jack always stayed on top.

[image: wrong numero uno]

Then I thought I could use a `Stack`! That way I could directly control which widgets are laid out above the other ones. However... I ran into this problem where the cable box-bottom was rendering *behind* cable box-top, instead of underneath it.

[image: this is really hard apparently]

Now, obviously the solution is to just use `Positioned` on cable box-bottom and set it so it's right under cable box-top. But in order to do that, I need to know cable box-top's height.

Unfortunately that seems to be a very hard problem to solve (one that confused the crap out of Chat-GPT, at least), as it involves getting a `RenderBox` and checking the size at *just* the right time in order to get the correct size. It has to be after the widgets are built (or else it's null), but I also tried `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()`, and the `RenderBox` always gave me a size with `0.0` as its height. However, using an `await Future.delayed()` with something longer than ~80ms allowed me to get the correct height value I was looking for. But this feels *really* hacky, and I know flutter is a much more sophisticated framework than to require me to do something like that.

So what do I do? I want some combination of `Column` and `Stack`, which I could accomplish with just `Stack` if I knew the widget's height after building it, but that doesn't seem to work using the often-suggested `addPostFrameCallback()` technique. Any ideas on what I could do here?

Comment: Have you tried the ClipRRect so the plug widget disappears if it is passing the available area? I suppose that a structure with Stack, like the one you have now, would be possible to test.

Comment: Huh, didn't know about that widget. Although, once I started to try it, I realized I would run into the same problem of "how far down do I need to place this widget" in order to get it to clip in the right place. You can also use a `Stack` to try to clip things, but again, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a little disappointed that this is the best way I ended up finding... What I'm going to go with is what I did to get my "what I want" picture. Basically in a `Stack` I rendered a `Column` with the cable box-top and cable box-bottom the way I wanted, then added the audio jack widget, then added another `Column` with the same settings, but only with the cable box-top. It's not ideal, because I'm creating two widgets for the top, but I guess it's not too different than what's done with other graphics engines sometimes.